# Android always in portrait mode not working

Tags: android, orientation, portrait

I want to run my application always in portrait mode. I searched and found the code below, then I added to manifest file.

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

but my application still chancing orientation when I press CRTL+F12 on AVD. 
How can I force my application always run in portrait mode?

Ps: I tried the code reverse. (Second line first then first line)

Comment: you need to put this setting on EVERY activity, you wish to limit to orientation mode portrait

Comment: the order of the code lines doesnt matter

Comment: You should put it on your <application> tag instead of <activity>.

Comment: add your manifest file there

Comment: Test with real Android device.

Comment: thanks a lot. I added to all activities and my problem solved. I was adding it to application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add that in the activity element, not the application element?

```
 <activity 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"  
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" >
 </activity>
```